# What is the difference between using HttpUwsgiModule for NGINX and using NGINX as a reverseproxy to uWSGI?

Tags: python, nginx, webserver, reverse-proxy, uwsgi

Using `HttpUwsgiModule` with NGINX to control uWSGI has become quite popular since its release.

I was wondering though, what is the advantage of it, compared to using NGINX as a reverse-proxy to uWSGI application?

What are the gains and losses in two differing use cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, when you use `HttpUwsgiModule` NGINX speaks the `uwsgi protocol` and it can leave out useless informations of the `http protocol` leading to less overhead and thus better performance.

Comment: Thank you @Paolo. Great simple answers.